# Easy way to see the Bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with a simple HTML page using Bootstrap and I would love to have a way to visualize the columns, as in see them "underneath" the actual content as a different shade for example, something like the one at [Frameless](http://framelessgrid.com/).  Is there a way to get that functionality easy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use some CSS with the `background` to see the grid :

```css
[class*="span"] { background: #EEF; }
[class*="span"] [class*="span"] { background: #FEE; }
```

[Demo 1 (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/eq953/)

As suggested by Pavlo, you can also use a semi-transparent color which would give you different shades depending on the nesting ([`rgba` browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value#Browser_Compatibility)) :

```css
[class^="span"] { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3); }
```

[Demo 2 (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rtRn2/)

The same goes with `.row` or any element of the grid.

*Note: the choice between `*=` or `^=` doesn't really matter in this case, see [this (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) for more info*

Comment: Why not to put some semi-trasparent color on the background, so it will "add up" on column on the top of column.

Comment: @Pavlo The few times I tried, I ended up with barely distinguishable colors - where the few (depending on your needs) nested rules assure you the best clarity.

Comment: Instead of using a background, use 

    border-style: solid;

Answer (score 41):

Updated Sherbrow's answer for Bootstrap 3:

```
div[class="row"] {
    outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

div[class^="col-"] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: This highlights the row, but doesn't highlight the cols because the gutter (spacing between columns) isn't revealed: http://codeply.com/go/NX0SqKupbB

Comment: How about bootstrapv4?

Comment: @Nathan H - Seems to do a similar job with BS4, but admittedly I haven't looked at BS4 in depth.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or another webkit browser, go to the page below and "install" the bookmarklet by dragging it to your bookmarks.

Then you can view the grid for any page using foundation or bootstrap by clicking the bookmarklet and choose the framework.

http://alefeuvre.github.io/foundation-grid-displayer/

Comment: Found this looking for a Chrome-only bug with Bootstrap columns.  Note to new viewers that Chrome is no longer web-kit, and has invented their own html/css system, so we get to build everything twice again, like with old IE.

Comment: Works like a dream in Firefox. Brilliant. Thanks. Once 'installed', click the bookmark link to toggle on and off.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chrome, you can try this extension [Bootstrap Grid Overlay](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bootstrap-grid-overlay/mnlklmelflkheijccafopdohgclfefcg)

I have used it with bootstrap v4, working fine with showing the columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use some **simple jQuery/javascript** function from console if I need.
<strike>It only works with a 12 grid, but you'll be smart. You may not close the overlay or click links. Just reload the page.</strike>

```
function bootstrap_overlay() {

  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var grid = 12, 
  columns = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
  div = document.createElement('div');

  div.className ='span1';
  while (grid--) {
    columns.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true));
  }
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
      overlay.height(docHeight)
          .css({
           "opacity" : 0.4,
           "position": "absolute",
           "top": 0,
           "left": 0,
           "width": "100%",
           "z-index": 5000
          })          
          .append('<div class="container"><div class="row"></div></div>')
          .click(function(){ $(this).remove(); })
          .find('.row').append(columns);
   $("body").append(overlay);
   $("#overlay .span1").css({
       "opacity" : 0.4,
       "background-color": "red"
    }).height(docHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since different containers on the same page can have different columns, a solution will have to support visualizing this. Just displaying a colored overlay is not that visually apparent. One easy solution is to just add temporary column elements at the top of each section that you want to visualize, such as the following snippet:

```
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-info'>1</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-success'>2</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-warning'>3</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-danger'>4</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-info'>5</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-success'>6</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-warning'>7</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-danger'>8</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-info'>9</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-success'>10</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-warning'>11</div>
<div class='col-xs-1 alert alert-danger'>12</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7zea43o8/7/

Comment: This is pretty simple and great for what I was looking to do thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 has different class names (`span*` > `col-*-*`), and uses padding to create the gutter (spacing) between columns so simply putting a `background-color` in the columns won't show the gutter.

For Bootstrap 3, you can add `background-clip: content-box` to only show the background color within the content area...

```
 .row [class*='col-'] {
      background-color: #ffeeee;
      background-clip: content-box;
      min-height: 20px;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/pejyqLlrBF