# Display grid (columns and gutters) in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen this come up a few times but for older versions of Bootstrap.

Looking for an easy way to highlight the grid - both the columns and the gutters.

Here's what I found so far:

https://gist.github.com/procload/1988163 - returns an error with `@function`

https://github.com/ricardovf/bogrid - `Ctrl-G` still brings up the find

http://alefeuvre.github.io/foundation-grid-displayer/ - Sort of works, shows columns in full width but not anything narrower.

[Easy way to see the Bootstrap grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770591/easy-way-to-see-the-bootstrap-grid) - Works for Bootstrap 2.3, doesn't work for 3.  However it will only show the combined columns, not each individual column within combined columns. (Edited)

[Edit]  Ideally, the column overlay would show all the columns that the examples on this page are displaying: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Open to any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the HTML/css of the last example, and I get some result,

```
[class*="col"]:hover { background: #000; }
[class*="col"] [class*="col"]:hover { background: red; }
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/xFq47/

is that what you'r looking for?

Comment: Thanks!  It's on the right track (and thanks for those changes - I see what I did wrong).  Problem is that where that example has a span of 6 cols (in BS 3 that might be col-md-6 for others looking for solutions instead of span6 in the jsfiddle)  there's a background that highlights the entire span of 6 columns.  I want to see those 6 columns and the gutters in between them.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the demo, I just guessed from the code. Just to be sure that we talk about the same thing, on BS3 : the screen is splitted in 12 column, so col-*-6 means 50% of the screen. the middle key (lg,md,sm,xs) tells at which moment you want your block to go inline (not floating) anymore, as a responsive feature. I am not sure what you mean by gutters, the container padding? the margin?

Comment: @Gutter - sorry yes, the column padding if possible.  In terms of seeing the columns, I'd want to see those six columns overlaid on top of that col-*-6.

Comment: Just made an edit - would hope that the column overlay would show all the columns on this page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xFq47/3/
I updated the fiddle. It does cover any kind of col (lg,md,sm,xs) and any number of column (12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1). But I am still not sure what you are looking for. Do you have an online example working and having this feature to provide me?

Comment: His code:  [class*="col"] { background-color:rgba(0,85,142,0.2);  border:1px solid rgba(0,85,142,1);   padding:15px;}
   [class*="col"]:hover { background-color:rgba(194,57,142,0.2); border:1px solid rgba(194,57,142,1);}
   [class*="col"] [class*="col"]:hover { background-color:rgba(194,57,142,0.2);  border:1px solid rgba(194,57,142,1);}

Comment: @Gisto - WHY WOULDNT YOU ACCEPT / THANK Yoann is jus beyond me !

Answer (score 1):

Use this to highlight the grid columns:

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
      background-color: #ffeeee;
      background-clip: content-box;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/pejyqLlrBF

Comment: [class*="col"] { background-color:rgba(0,85,142,0.2); border:1px solid rgba(0,85,142,1); padding:15px;} [class*="col"]:hover { background-color:rgba(194,57,142,0.2); border:1px solid rgba(194,57,142,1);} [class*="col"] [class*="col"]:hover { background-color:rgba(194,57,142,0.2); border:1px solid rgba(194,57,142,1);}